# Sort array of integers and display value on inputs

Tags: javascript, sorting, ranking

I have a website with a lot of input fields and I'd like to sort the datas inside them.

[image]

As you can see, I'd like to sort the column of total scores and have the position on the MVP input field. To do this, I thought to use the javascript function `.sort();`.

```
function sortmvp() {
    var mvp = new Array();
    mvp[0] = parseInt(document.getElementById('p1_5h').value);
    mvp[1] = parseInt(document.getElementById('p2_5h').value);
    mvp[2] = parseInt(document.getElementById('p3_5h').value);
    mvp[3] = parseInt(document.getElementById('p4_5h').value);
    mvp[4] = parseInt(document.getElementById('p5_5h').value);
    mvp[5] = parseInt(document.getElementById('p6_5h').value);

    mvp.sort();
}
```

Those `p1_5h`, `p2_5h`, `p1_5h`... are the inputs of the **Total** column. At this point I only have sorted the datas on my array but I have to display them.

The problem is that I don't know how to display the correct positions (1,2,3,4...) in the correct input as you can see in the image above. Any suggestion?

Here you can see the HTML code of the table: http://jsfiddle.net/ajLLU/1/

HTML

```
<fieldset class="a" style="width:90%">
    <legend><b>Individuals</b>
    </legend>
    <div style="height:240px;width:100%;overflow-y:scroll; border:1px solid #D8D8D8;">
        <form name="individszsz" action="individuals.js, update_gps();">
            <table id="tabini11" border="0" align="center" style="width:550px">
                <tr>
                    <td width="100px" valign="bottom">
                        <p align="center"><b> Home Clan </b>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="50px">
                        <p align="center"><b>GP1</b>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="50px">
                        <p align="center"><b>GP2</b>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="50px">
                        <p align="center"><b> GP3  </b>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="50px">
                        <p align="center"><b> Total</b>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="50px">
                        <p align="center"><b> Average</b>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom">
                        <p align="center"><b> MVP</b>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="80px" valign="bottom">
                        <input id="p1_1h" type="text" name="p1_1h" value="" style="width:100%">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p1_2h" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p1_3h" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p1_4h" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p1_5h" type="text" value="0" readonly style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p1_6h" type="text" value="0" readonly style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="mvp1" type="text" value="0" readonly style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="80px" valign="bottom">
                        <input id="p2_1h" type="text" value="" style="width:100%">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p2_2h" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p2_3h" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p2_4h" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p2_5h" type="text" value="0" readonly style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p2_6h" type="text" value="0" readonly style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="mvp2" type="text" value="0" readonly style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="80px" valign="bottom">
                        <input id="p3_1h" type="text" value="" style="width:100%">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p3_2h" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p3_3h" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p3_4h" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p3_5h" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" readonly onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p3_6h" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" readonly onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="mvp3" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" readonly onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="80px" valign="bottom">
                        <input id="p4_1h" type="text" value="" style="width:100%">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p4_2h" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p4_3h" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p4_4h" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p4_5h" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" readonly onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p4_6h" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" readonly onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="mvp4" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" readonly onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="80px" valign="bottom">
                        <input id="p5_1h" type="text" value="" style="width:100%">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p5_2h" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p5_3h" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p5_4h" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p5_5h" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" readonly onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p5_6h" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" readonly onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="mvp5" type="text" value="0" style="width:100" readonly onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="80px" valign="bottom">
                        <input id="p6_1h" type="text" value="" style="width:100%">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p6_2h" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p6_3h" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p6_4h" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p6_5h" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p6_6h" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="mvp6" type="text" value="0" style="width:100" readonly onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table id="tabini12" border="0" align="center" style="width:550px">
                <tr>
                    <td width="80px" valign="bottom">
                        <p align="center"><b> Versus Clan </b>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <p align="center"><b>GP1</b>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <p align="center"><b>GP2</b>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <p align="center"><b> GP3  </b>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <p align="center"><b> Total</b>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <p align="center"><b> Average</b>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <p align="center"><b> MVP</b>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="80px" valign="bottom">
                        <input id="p1_1o" type="text" name="p1_1h" value="" style="width:100%">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p1_2o" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p1_3o" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p1_4o" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p1_5o" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" readonlyonchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p1_6o" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" readonly onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="mvp7" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" readonly onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="80px" valign="bottom">
                        <input id="p2_1o" type="text" value="" style="width:100%">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p2_2o" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p2_3o" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p2_4o" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p2_5o" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" readonly onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p2_6o" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" readonly onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="mvp8" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" readonly onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="80px" valign="bottom">
                        <input id="p3_1o" type="text" value="" style="width:100%">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p3_2o" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p3_3o" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p3_4o" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p3_5o" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" readonly onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p3_6o" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" readonly onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="mvp9" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" readonly onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="80px" valign="bottom">
                        <input id="p4_1o" type="text" value="" style="width:100%">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p4_2o" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p4_3o" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p4_4o" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p4_5o" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" readonly onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p4_6o" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" readonly onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="mvp10" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" readonly onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="80px" valign="bottom">
                        <input id="p5_1o" type="text" value="" style="width:100%">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p5_2o" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p5_3o" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p5_4o" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p5_5o" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" readonly onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p5_6o" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" readonly onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="mvp11" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" readonly onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="80px" valign="bottom">
                        <input id="p6_1o" type="text" value="" style="width:100%">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p6_2o" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p6_3o" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p6_4o" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p6_5o" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" readonly onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="p6_6o" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" readonly onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                    <td valign="bottom" width="40px">
                        <input id="mvp12" type="text" value="0" style="width:100%" readonly onchange="individuals(); update_gps(); calc();">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Javascript

```
function calc() {
    var h1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('h1').value);
    var h2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('h2').value);
    var h3 = parseInt(document.getElementById('h3').value);
    var o1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('o1').value);
    var o2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('o2').value);
    var o3 = parseInt(document.getElementById('o3').value);

    var toth = h1 + h2 + h3;
    var toto = o1 + o2 + o3;

    document.getElementById('htot').value = toth;
    document.getElementById('otot').value = toto;


    document.getElementById('diff1').value = h1 - o1;
    document.getElementById('diff2').value = h2 - o2;
    document.getElementById('diff3').value = h3 - o3;
    document.getElementById('difftot').value = toth - toto;

    htot = document.getElementById('htot');
    otot = document.getElementById('otot');

    if (htot.value == otot.value) {
        htot.style.color = 'blue';
        otot.style.color = 'blue';
    } else {
        if (htot.value > otot.value) {
            htot.style.color = 'green';
            otot.style.color = 'red';
        } else {
            otot.style.color = 'green';
            htot.style.color = 'red';
        }
    }

    var totals = [],
        indices = [];
    for (var i = 0, i < 6; i++) {
        totals[i] = parseInt(document.getElementById('p' + (i + 1) + '_5h').value, 10);
        indices[i] = i;
    }
    indices.sort(function (a, b) {
        return totals[a] - totals[b];
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < indices.length; i++)
    document.getElementById('mvp' + (indices[i] + 1)).value = (i + 1);

}
```

Comment: I have had success using a javascript library called Tidy Table. It allows the user to sort on any of the columnss and looks nice. http://labs.mbrooks.info/demos/Tidy-Table/

Comment: Are these `#pX_5h` fields the ones in the MVP or the ones in the Totals column?

Comment: #pX_5h indicates the fields of Totals columns, MVP columns' has the input called #mvpX

Comment: Can you provide the HTML of your table?

Comment: Make an array of each total and sort them in a descendant order, so the biggest is the first element. Then just output the result.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ajLLU/

Comment: And do you want the sort to happen dynamically as things are typed in or on a submit?

Comment: It would have also been useful to include the JS functions used for that HTML in the jsfiddle too.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ajLLU/1/ --> I've posted the HTML code with a part of the Javascript.

Comment: `individuals`? `update_gps`?

Comment: update_gps is a php script and individuals calculates the scores you type. As I said I posted only a part of the HTML code, what you see is the essential

Comment: And you wanted code based on the scores, right? Which are calculated as you type, right?

Comment: @Xotic750 yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't want to sort the total values, but their indices *by the respective value*. That way you still know which index belongs to which field.

```
var totals = [],
    indices = [];
for (var i=0; i<6; i++) {
    totals[i] = parseInt(document.getElementById('p'+(i+1)+'_5h').value, 10);
    indices[i] = i;
}
indices.sort(function(a, b) {
    return totals[a] - totals[b];
});
for (var i=0; i<indices.length; i++)
    document.getElementById('mvp'+(indices[i]+1)).value = (i+1);
```

Comment: (var i=0, i<6; i++) --> fix with the ; instead of the , ;)

Comment: @DK64: Thanks, you could've proposed that [edit] yourself :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, same principle as the accepted answer by @Bergi I took your jsfiddle and cleaned it up (removed inline Javascript and CSS), hopefully it will give you further ideas, and came up with the following working example.

CSS

```
fieldset.a {
    width: 90%;
}
fieldset.a legend {
    font-weight: bold;
}
fieldset.a > div:nth-of-type(1) {
    height: 240px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border :1px solid #D8D8D8;
}
fieldset.a table {
    border: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 550px;
}
fieldset.a td {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
fieldset.a thead td:nth-of-type(1) {
    width: 100px;
}
fieldset.a thead td:nth-of-type(2) {
    width: 50px;
}
fieldset.a thead td:nth-of-type(3) {
    width: 50px;
}
fieldset.a thead td:nth-of-type(4) {
    width: 50px;
}
fieldset.a thead td:nth-of-type(5) {
    width: 50px;
}
fieldset.a thead td:nth-of-type(6) {
    width: 50px;
}
fieldset.a thead td:nth-of-type(7) {
    width: 50px;
}
fieldset.a input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<fieldset class="a">
    <legend>Individuals</legend>
    <div>
        <form name="individszsz" action="">
            <table id="tabini11">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Home Clan</td>
                        <td>GP1</td>
                        <td>GP2</td>
                        <td>GP3</td>
                        <td>Total</td>
                        <td>Average</td>
                        <td>MVP</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tboby>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p1_1h" type="text" name="p1_1h">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p1_2h" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p1_3h" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p1_4h" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p1_5h" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p1_6h" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="mvp1" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p2_1h" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p2_2h" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p2_3h" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p2_4h" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p2_5h" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p2_6h" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="mvp2" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p3_1h" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p3_2h" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p3_3h" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p3_4h" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p3_5h" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p3_6h" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="mvp3" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p4_1h" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p4_2h" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p4_3h" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p4_4h" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p4_5h" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p4_6h" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="mvp4" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p5_1h" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p5_2h" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p5_3h" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p5_4h" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p5_5h" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p5_6h" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="mvp5" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p6_1h" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p6_2h" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p6_3h" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p6_4h" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p6_5h" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p6_6h" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="mvp6" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tboby>
            </table>
            <table id="tabini12">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Versus Clan</td>
                        <td>GP1</td>
                        <td>GP2</td>
                        <td>GP3</td>
                        <td>Total</td>
                        <td>Average</td>
                        <td>MVP</td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p1_1o" type="text" name="p1_1h">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p1_2o" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p1_3o" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p1_4o" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p1_5o" type="text" readonly">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p1_6o" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="mvp7" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p2_1o" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p2_2o" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p2_3o" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p2_4o" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p2_5o" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p2_6o" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="mvp8" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p3_1o" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p3_2o" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p3_3o" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p3_4o" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p3_5o" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p3_6o" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="mvp9" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p4_1o" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p4_2o" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p4_3o" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p4_4o" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p4_5o" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p4_6o" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="mvp10" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p5_1o" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p5_2o" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p5_3o" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p5_4o" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p5_5o" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p5_6o" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="mvp11" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p6_1o" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p6_2o" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p6_3o" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p6_4o" type="text">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p6_5o" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="p6_6o" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="mvp12" type="text" readonly>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Javascript

```
function calc(e) {
    var target = e.target,
        inputs = target.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("input"),
        allTbodyInputs = target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("input"),
        length = 4,
        positions = [],
        total = 0,
        average,
        i;

    for (i = 1; i < length; i += 1) {
        total += parseInt(inputs[i].value, 10) || 0;
    }

    average = total / 3;
    inputs[4].value = total;
    inputs[5].value = average.toFixed(2);

    for (i = 0, length = allTbodyInputs.length; i < length; i += 1) {
        if (/^p\d_6[ho]$/.test(allTbodyInputs[i].id)) { 
            positions.push({
                element: allTbodyInputs[i + 1],
                value: parseFloat(allTbodyInputs[i].value) || 0
            });
        }
    }

    positions.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (a.value === b.value) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (a.value > b.value) {
            return -1;
        }

        return 1;
    })


    for (i = 0, length = positions.length; i < length; i += 1) {
        positions[i].element.value = i + 1;
    }
}

var onChangeInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
    length,
    index;

for (index = 0, length = onChangeInputs.length; index < length; index += 1) {
    if (/^p\d_[234][ho]$/.test(onChangeInputs[index].id)) { 
        onChangeInputs[index].addEventListener("change", calc, false);
    }
}
```

On <kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/nFV7W/)</kbd>